# Predicting patients' probabilities from different classification models

Tags: machine-learning, probability, predictive-models, supervised-learning

Suppose I am a doctor trying to predict the probability of a patient getting a heart attack. The way I would approach this, in a clinical setting, is by using a logistic regression. For exmaple: P(HA) = 1/1+e^-(b0 + b1age + b2race + b3sex + ... + bnvariable_n).

Is it possible to obtain predicted probabilites from other classification models? Say I used XGboost and it had a better performance than logistic regression for my classification. I then chose the 10 most important features in the model. I would like to obtain an equation that predicts that a patient would get a heart attack knowing their 10 characteristics ? I do not want to only classify the person, I would like to obtain a probability. The reason I am asking this is because I would like to predict the different probabilities of different combinations of characteristics of high risk groups. i.e I would like to obtain different probabilites' profiles given the different combinations of 10 characteristics. Is this possible for all following classification models (linear SVM, KNN,LDA) ?

Comment: xgboost will give you accurate probabilities, you just have to make sure you train/validate with logloss rather than just classification metric

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks for the answer. That helps a lot. Do you have an idea about other models ? (SVM, RF, KNN, LDA) ?

Answer (score 1):

While XGBoost can give probabilities, watch out for saying that you want to use those probabilities over those of a logistic regression that has lower classification accuracy. Accuracy is calculated for just one threshold (typically $0.5$, which might be wildly inappropriate for your task), while the predicted probabilities are independent of the threshold. The XGBoost might be worse than the logistic regression at estimating probabilities despite being better in terms of classification accuracy at one threshold.

Most models return probabilities or some kind of score that is on a continuum (not just the category) that can be transformed into a probability.

Explicitly addressing the models you mentioned:

Support vector classifiers can be wrestled with to give probabilities. Platt scaling is a topic you might want to learn more about for this.

K-nearest neighbors can be considered to give probabilities if you take the probability as the proportion of each class represented among the neighbors.

Linear discriminant analysis seems to have a probabilistic flavor, as is discussed by Ioffe (2006).

Watch out for the fact that models can give probabilities that might lead to accurate models at a particular threshold but might not reflect the true probability of event occurrence (e.g., probabilities estimated at $0.9$, yet the event only happens $65\%$ fo the time). Such models can have their outputs calibrated, but it is not a given that this can be done. Even if it can be done, it is important to know that this might be a necessary step.

The `rms` package in `R` software gives the ability to check for probability calibration.

```r
library(rms)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x1 <- runif(N)
x2 <- runif(N)
z <- 3*x1 - 3*x2
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
L <- rms::lrm(y ~ x1 + x2, x = T, y = T)
cal <- rms::calibrate(L, B = 1000)
plot(cal)
```

[image: Calibration plot]

Ideally, the calibration curve will equal the line $y=x$, since we want the probability of event occurrence to equal the predicted probability. Since the calibration curve is close to the $y=x$ line, the calibration seems to be pretty good.

**REFERENCE**

Ioffe, Sergey. "Probabilistic linear discriminant analysis." Computer Vision–ECCV 2006: 9th European Conference on Computer Vision, Graz, Austria, May 7-13, 2006, Proceedings, Part IV 9. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2006.

Comment: Very helpful answer in the context of binomial modeling (+1). There's a question whether a binomial model is appropriate in the scenario of the OP; survival analysis might be needed. The principles you describe nevertheless hold for either type of outcome.